# Updating a drush command from drush 7 to drush 8

Tags: drush

what to do if there is a drush command file worked with drush 7 but doesn't work with drush 8. The official docs seem not to have an upgrade guide for this.

Comment: What is the exact command that doesn't work in Drush 8? Maybe another command replaced it, but if you don't say which command you used in Drush 7, we cannot answer you.

Comment: its the radix command from the radix theme. I found  this temporarily fix;

 `drush --include=./sites/all/themes/radix radix` 

but now i am not shure why this is necessary

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to refer to a bug in an drupal module and should be handled on drupal.org. See https://www.drupal.org/node/2552571

Answer (score 1):

Drush makes an attempt to never run any code associated with a module or theme unless that module or theme is enabled. This protection is often more conservative than necessary, as some Drush extensions do not exercise any code that requires a Drupal bootstrap.

None the less, Drush 8 is more rigorous than Drush 7 was. Drush 7 would search for extensions in all of the theme folders regardless of whether the corresponding themes were enabled. Drush 8, on the other hand, ignores extensions stored with disabled themes.

Include paths provided specifically via the --include option are always searched, though; Drush makes no attempt to determine if the specified path happens to correspond to a disabled theme. This is why the workaround you found works.

Comment: Ok what if I tell you that the theme is active when this happens and drush 7 recognizes the command while drush 8 doesn't recognize it. Here is the issue with a screenshot and the steps to reproduce. I am not sure if this is drush or the command file.

https://www.drupal.org/node/2552571#comment-10738508

Comment: Sounds like a Drush bug that should be reported in the issue queue.